# Fit of 2D Scatter Data From Multiple Objects in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, curve-fitting

I am looking for a way to fit a curve to a set of x,y scatter data that would describe the most typical shape (average? best fit? not sure what the correct term would be).

So far I tried several variations on polyfitting with  but this is not really working at all. The lower order fits don't capture the shape well and higher order fits have all kinds of overfitting or undesired end effects. I also looked at turning this data into a heat map, which does give me a decent visual of what I'm looking for but doesn't give me a way to describe the shape as a function of x position. Open to any ideas... Thanks all!

---

The data consists of multiple "captures" of 2d coordinate data. Each capture is a string of x,y coordinates that represent the outer profile of an object. All the objects are similar on the macro level but they each have differences. The attached image of the tree trunks illustrates the type of information, all of them are round-ish but clearly have differences in the profile.

[image: Tree ring visual of data captures, each color would be a single capture/tree.]

---

Here is a scatter plot of my actual data. Each color represents an individual capture/object. The red line is what I imagine the desired output/fit to be.

[image: Scatter plot of my data with desired output in red]

See bottom of post for a smaller subset of the data for the sake of having something to discuss, in csv format.

---

Read in sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data.csv', )
for capture_number in range(max(data.capture_number)+1):
    x = data.x[data.capture_number == capture_number]
    y = data.y[data.capture_number == capture_number]
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.plot(x,y, alpha = 0.3)
```

That gives me this plot. Each color is an individual capture/object.
[image: Plot showing subset of sample data]

---

Then do some fitting.

```
data_sorted = data.sort_values(by='x')

xs = np.linspace(min(data.x), max(data.x), 100)

p_3 = np.polyfit(data_sorted.x, data_sorted.y, 3)
p_5 = np.polyfit(data_sorted.x, data_sorted.y, 5)
p_10 = np.polyfit(data_sorted.x, data_sorted.y, 10)

plt.figure()

plt.plot(xs, np.polyval(p_3, xs), c='m')
plt.plot(xs, np.polyval(p_5, xs), c='c')
plt.plot(xs, np.polyval(p_10, xs), c='r')
plt.scatter(data.x, data.y, s=1, marker='o')

plt.legend(['3rd order fit', '5th order fit', '10th order fit' , 'scatter data'])
```

[image: That gives me this plot: Plot with fits]

---

Sample Data:

```
x,y,capture_number
-92.48513173328318,174.46181346779125,0
-102.34411197872745,143.10470214178093,0
-105.06373626025295,84.86118244975245,0
-98.61190594972697,46.294407824292506,0
-63.99942017496949,9.215007045016817,0
-18.011106513233937,15.073676637862253,0
-2.4091675236573122,66.79032858512424,0
-2.793581679386326,88.45604299278679,0
-0.037191373829076044,83.57866552583225,1
-3.372037438453564,68.37521993841754,1
-6.3020594949810445,32.46959340011879,1
-23.646729955279078,4.201053940534801,1
-60.723536889231134,11.131211365998759,1
-78.67812538210005,26.701665893588228,1
-85.36645115296895,47.23880092937693,1
-95.4513113514432,69.35182638987914,1
-99.18677616845986,76.78728094217132,1
-11.57760873856192,97.62529943790491,2
-2.3850312567657643,46.40555613892471,2
-30.972436937263602,5.161311187235333,2
-80.50235616412658,45.73866780689221,2
-100.84679376767056,82.57165001365009,2
-1.579108157217389,93.4006768863743,3
-1.0342435877346552,79.90689875086049,3
-5.389782177008227,57.17976276644515,3
-6.933090791486306,30.294195133777237,3
-18.071889237594064,4.123664591593948,3
-35.68449626893269,3.6709119699324777,3
-52.024640946341634,10.892909487984635,3
-74.60092054794526,30.140927095466658,3
-91.11409785124107,60.15913910456948,3
-95.08970881852622,71.32115598902,3
-4.170806597499514,95.98055160555235,4
-2.4180312611738395,85.98687321564216,4
-0.5498018356144946,62.4353954245081,4
-2.0744302915463395,29.14987932885067,4
-4.435901811714583,9.792402649412317,4
-16.614338883267788,3.709200622148345,4
-34.87621519152463,2.995086459817584,4
-50.85275052997459,3.9733989189931154,4
-69.99280429729266,18.813544393730336,4
-84.71518869796297,39.58603196895316,4
-96.85090881319562,57.03667006335702,4
-107.87093848852234,85.48437316116156,4
-109.39596178555179,109.19679183900347,4
-107.54308863516981,116.12024736811875,4
0.5117546553123122,78.90192280827411,5
-8.95047861926479,47.224485130899815,5
-11.24909392853944,25.00751807126977,5
-30.443249589625818,5.731132987759837,5
-61.93003194342436,10.249018898126533,5
-78.02611959770444,31.457502011386566,5
-89.74733849583858,54.007959025287285,5
-98.60749645003874,77.54827040087625,5
-100.51048477456361,88.45519980721456,5
-10.12650583863164,132.11572810052456,6
-8.092609250243742,89.89042433421311,6
-3.619178885745626,52.07668960611805,6
-0.9181312645347878,24.215983486617777,6
-15.363333435476594,2.4053207891565536,6
-34.901522245357214,4.831842592092085,6
-50.57437592147933,9.90012604519583,6
-66.10788430707454,19.876547966332367,6
-79.99990573199646,35.55513375638101,6
-95.9648607113633,53.26275540580688,6
-102.11805211534988,97.94937981624,6
-99.55995261744383,130.16356048679103,6
-6.463495249711035,98.7572335450711,7
-0.6995064583571309,69.63788098118992,7
-11.265182407597008,17.91027394127386,7
-42.92158289984183,-2.2681684837896534,7
-76.30092222746524,36.875233496201446,7
-91.83228706419811,68.7361985764675,7
-94.15078846035587,74.31891629844836,7
-0.8557562431032705,117.05886485812867,8
-1.4316909413126913,69.35863586507791,8
-1.732543610955167,31.312002315071403,8
-8.002117735463669,6.822473131379365,8
-39.07947403605981,3.0170544498847915,8
-81.05156816306311,28.09752208418372,8
-96.45367007880188,87.44681780046406,8
-93.94267869648395,129.9987553469081,8
-92.66722585758654,138.25266699687177,8
-2.215747392819274,83.4829833439352,9
-4.456089705671695,45.43342366742096,9
-26.515974744921557,1.541075059187552,9
-67.03191101940496,12.648076176354751,9
-92.9866094421785,56.79854957617513,9
-98.90124191249355,73.7029457010593,9
```

Comment: Are you looking to fit a function or a general relation (e.g. circle, eclipse, hyperbola)? You're unlikely to get a good fit using a polynomial if you want the final curve to be a non-function.

Comment: @JethroCao - I am not sure what the correct terminology is for what I'm looking for. At a high level, I am looking for some method to define the curve so that I can import the curve it into CAD software and 3d print a part that is based on the curve.

I agree that polynomial fit is not the right approach, I was only using it because that's the closest thing I am familiar with.

Comment: Not saying I know for certain that this approach will solve your problem, but I'd look into SVM (support vector machines), which is used in ML for both classification and regression. Here's the API for what you'd likely want to explore: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html

Comment: I looked into the docs a little bit but wasn't able to get very far. It seems like there may be something there but I need to get way more familiar with tuning the parameters for good fits.

Comment: Yes, SVM isn't the easiest thing to wrap your head around if you're new to it, but it's worth learning regardless imo. Another potential way to tackle the problem is bisecting your dataset into two halves, so that each can be approximated by an actual function, then do regression separately on the "upper" and "lower" halves of your dataset. And finally, you need to join the two regression curves together, taking extra consideration on the points that they should be joined at, in order to ensure both continuity and smoothness; perhaps even applying that as constraints to the regression.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about the comment from you Jethro and started to break it up into halves, and then quarters. Then a colleague suggested just using polar coords to do the fit. Since the shapes are kind of circular to begin with that  ended up working really well.

Process was:

1. Convert scatter data to polar cs.
2. Create fit options in polar cs.
3. Convert back to cartesian. I evaluated the fit function in polar, then converted the output points into x,y.

Issues:

- I had to use a high order polynomial fit to match the shape of the data well. There was some overfitting, especially at the end of the ranges but that isn't really the region of interest for me.
- I think there is still opportunity for a much better fit in polar cs. I took the first thing that looked good and may spend a little more time tryigng to dial it in later.

---

Here are a couple of the fits I tested, in polar CS.
[image]

---

Here is the fit I chose, mapped back to x,y. Polyfit, order 50.

[image]

---

And some code, in case someone else happens upon a similar issue.

```
def polar(x, y):
    r = (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** .5
    theta = np.arctan2(y,x)
    return r, theta

def cartersian(r, theta):
    x = r * np.cos(theta)
    y = r * np.sin(theta)
    return(x, y)

data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x_collector, 'y': y_collector})

#adjust to have data centered around reasonable origin for polar mapping. 
data['x_centered'] = data['x'] - np.average(data.x)
data['y_centered'] = data['y'] - np.average(data.y)

# map to polar cs
data['polar'] = data.apply(lambda row: polar(row.x_centered, row.y_centered), axis = 1)

# split in to 2 columns
data[['r', 'theta']] = pd.DataFrame(data['polar'].tolist(), index=data.index)

# translate everything so that 0, 2pi captured my data in continuous manor. 
data['theta'] = data.apply(lambda row: row['theta']- (np.pi*2) if row['theta'] > (np.pi/2) else row['theta'], axis=1)
data = data.sort_values(by='theta')


# calculate fit
theta_fit = np.linspace(min(data.theta), max(data.theta), 100 )
p50 = np.polyfit(data.theta, data.r, 50)
rfit50 = np.polyval(p50, theta_fit)
plt.plot(theta_fit, rfit50, '-', lw = 0.5, label = 'polyfit, order: 50')

# map back to x,y
x50_fit = []
y50_fit = []
x_points = []
y_points = []
for point in list(zip(rfit50, theta_fit)):
    x_point, y_point = cartersian(point[0], point[1])
    x50_fit.append(x_point)
    y50_fit.append(y_point)
fit_plot = pd.DataFrame({'x': x50_fit, 'y': y50_fit})
fit_plot = fit_plot[fit_plot.y <= 85] #trim off the ends

plt.figure(dpi = 200)
plt.scatter(x_points, y_points, c = 'g', s = 0.1, label = 'Tracing Data', alpha = 0.05)    
plt.plot(fit_plot.x, fit_plot.y, '--m', label = 'Fit', alpha = 0.8)
plt.title('Cartesian Coords')

plt.legend()
```